# Is there any easy way in DolphinDB to accomplish what the **match** function does in R?

Tags: r, dolphindb

Is there any easy way in DolphinDB to accomplish what the `match` function does in R?

What `match` in R does is that it returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find` function in DolphinDB